# Not able to compare empty tags/elements in which one is self closed tag with attribute value and other one is normal tag with no attribute

Tags: java, xmlunit

`<addressLine2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:nil="1" />`

`<addressLine2></addressLine2>`

### Out put of Difference is :

`Expected attribute name 'nil' but was 'null' - comparing <addressLine2...> at /Envelope[1]/Body[1]/createOrder[1]/createOrderRequest[1]/order[1]/customer[1]/billingAddress[1]/addressLine2[1] to <addressLine2...> at /Envelope[1]/Body[1]/createOrder[1]/createOrderRequest[1]/order[1]/customer[1]/billingAddress[1]/addressLine2[1]`

I am using below to methods also.
`XMLUnit.setIgnoreDiffBetweenTextAndCDATA(Boolean.TRUE);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(Boolean.TRUE);`